# PHP Curl upload_content_length greater than filesize

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm working on a script to upload files to http://imagerelay.com. This is my first time using a REST API and cURL with PHP. There are two phases to the upload. First you submit metadata to the ImageRelay which includes the filesize for your local file. This returns an ID number which you use to build the URL for uploading the chunks (using CLI 'split' to generate). However, when I upload a file using cURL there are an extra 219 bytes added to each file. I suspect this is related to how cURL works, but I'm not sure how to correct the overage without manually increasing the filesize in phase 1 by 219bytes * x number of chunks.

Here is the response array received from the cURL request. The actual file chunk size is 1M (1,048,576 bytes), whereas the response shows 219 bytes more at 1048795

```
[http_code] => 201
[header_size] => 583
[request_size] => 346
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 2.039208
[namelookup_time] => 1.2E-5
[connect_time] => 0.040014
[pretransfer_time] => 0.13825
[size_upload] => 1048795
[size_download] => 1
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 514314
[download_content_length] => 1
[upload_content_length] => 1048795
[starttransfer_time] => 0.182222
```

Here's the relevant section of the code. `$file` represents the chunk, and `$resource` is pre-determined as it increments each chunk.

```
$ch = curl_init( $resource );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
$pdfData = array( 'file' => new CurlFile( "file-chunks/{$file}", 'application/octet-stream') );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I appreciate any help that can be provided. I've been working on this for a week and scouring the internet but I can't figure out why the filesize of the chunk doesn't match the `upload_content_length` or `size_upload`. I do not have the same issue when doing this over the command line with curl (and not PHP over CLI). Thank you!

[edit]Removed typo in first sentence (accidental paste!)[/edit]
[edit2]Added bounty[/edit]

Comment: HTTP multipart/form-data does have some additional overheads with form fields and file uploads (it has a sort of mini-header before the content), as well as boundary bytes that it adds.  I haven't checked, but perhaps cURL is including all that in its count.  Do you know the actual size of the file that gets sent to the other end?  If not, try pointing your code to upload to your own PHP script, or if you're able to, set up an intercepting proxy to see what exactly is being sent.

Comment: Zinga, this is the best feedback I've received yet. I wish you would have posted a reply with an example instead of the feedback and I'd have given you the bounty. Still have 3 hours, if you can do it by then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send file like this

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
);

$file = "/full/path/to/file.pdf"; // Full path to file

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The API for Image Relay states the Content-Type must be set to application/octet-stream. Do you think this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the option `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and check STDERR to see the complete payload.

You can also try to use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to check what goes on the wire. 
(It could be scary at first but fairly easy to use).